# Is normal for dog to play biting?

Tags: dogs, play, biting

I adopted a dog last week, and she was very nervous when she arrived home, but today I was surprised because she wanted to play a lot with me, jumping, running, but also biting (a lot).

She wants to bite me, and several stuff that is next to her. I want to know that if is normal to a dog and if I should let her play this way with me, or this will cause problem when she is an adult with more strength, or if this is a normal behavior related to her age and when she grow up, she will stop doing this.

PS: I'm fine with this kind of games, I'm not getting hurt (yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biting is very common at that age as they are still learning boundaries. We are currently dealing with a teething, mouthy two months old as well and when he gets mouthy with us we will redirect his biting to a toy or a chew. If he nips too hard (puppy teeth are SHARP!) I just respond with a loud yelp noise and will tap him lightly on the noise with my fingertip and he stops.

I would work on correcting the mouthiness now, although its not an aggressive behavior, it can easily develop into an annoying habit and nobody wants to deal with an adult dog who won't stop using their teeth.

Answer (score 2):

How old is she? She could be teething. I had the same issue with my German Shepherd. She started biting a lot! We later realised that it was because she started teething. She is now 2 years + and has toned down with her biting very much.

Comment: She is two months old

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta I suspect teething. She'll be biting everything and anything she can get her hands on. My puppy was like that. We got my dog a chew toy and that helped. We also made an 'ouch' sound whenever she bit too hard and left her. After a few times, she knew not too bit us that hard again.

Answer (score 1):

You may be fine with it, but it will scare some people and annoy others. Grabbing and jumping should be allowed only when a toy is involved, so she can learn when it is and isn't appropriate. It's your responsibility to teach her this.